# Bind RibbonComboBox.SelectionBoxItem

Tags: wpf, ribbon, ribbon-control

I'm trying to bind the item selected in a RibbonComboBox to a property of an object.  The problem I'm encountering is that the RibbonComboBox.SelectionBoxItem only provides a get accessor; therefore, I cannot bind it to anything in the XAML.

Any ideas how to bind the item to the property of an object?  I could use a regular ComboBox is there another more appropriate control?

```
xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"

<ribbon:RibbonComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionOfPossibleChoices}}"/
    SelectionBoxItem="{Binding Path=PropertyToBindTo}"/> <!--Not valid-->
```

Comment: Can't you just use a OneWayToSource binding?

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work.  The SelectionBoxItem doesn't have a set accessor at all so you can't set it to anything anywhere (XAML or code-behind).

Comment: OneWayToSource would not use a set accessor.  It would only change the bind source when you changed the combo box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RibbonComboBox is unlike ComboBox (which i, also, find confusing). Try this;

```
<ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
    <ribbon:RibbonGallery SelectedItem="{Binding Path=PropertyToBindTo}">
        <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionOfPossibleChoices}}" />
    </ribbon:RibbonGallery>
</ribbon:RibbonComboBox>
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribboncombobox.aspx) Reference

Comment: It also does not understand the `SelectedItem` binding very well at runtime (it always seems to "lose" the current value).